# iOS team provisioning profile under organizer in Xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store

I am using it for a few years, but every time again i have problems with it , now i really want to understand things, because i have a problem with provisioning.

What a developer should see in his organizer in Xcode , for each and every app that he wants to distribute ?

i have there a few things :

1. i have names of a development provisioning that i created in the portal. ( i don't have the names of the distributions file i have created, for non of the apps-even the one already at the store)
2. i have some sentence like : `iOS team provisioning profiles` , and some of them are with the app name at the end `"iOS team provisioning profile:com.company.app"` , but i have one that is just like `iOS team provisioning profile:*`

What is the different for each, how can i import that team profiles for a specific app( i did the whole process ten's of times(creating provisioings,download them,click them, etc), and i never can see the distribution on the store, only the appDev profile, and a few sentences like from what i stated here at number 2. (not for all of my apps ) .

now i get the know error :n`o provisioning for the executable..` when trying to distribute.
How can i manage this mess ???

Comment: xcode 5 manages provisioning profiles automatically. Are you using an older version?

Comment: no , i am in xcode 5 ..

Comment: Then you should choose automatic in the build settings for the provisioning profiles and let xcode do the thing for you (it even generates provisioning profiles if they are missing).

Comment: its not working . i still get that error. i just don't know what to do. 3 month of work and you can't upload your app to the store . now i see that  my previous apps that in the store already, also not working on the device under distribution+release . should they ? if you set it to distribution- it should work on the device anyway ?